# how to partition a harddrive for optimal performance?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, boot-partition

I have a 2TB hard drive and I have 4 partitions:

3 partitions of ~600GB each one (D,E,F) and 1 partition of ~200GB (C)

The problem is that my Windows partition (on C drive) is located between my drives E and F,
something like this: [image]
Is  there any problem if my Windows partition is not located at the start of the hard drive?

Comment: No. Why do you think this is a problem? If Windows is running, leave it alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place to install and allocate your operational system is at the beginning of the disk, I mean, on the most external phisical area of the disk. I already explained [a similar question](https://superuser.com/q/440338/79358) before but I will also post a part of it here in attempt to answer your question:

> The fist 0-10% area of your hard disk corresponds to the external area
>   of the disk, which gives the read speed a boost because the linear
>   speed of this area is higher compared to the internal area of your
>   disk(the last 90-100% of your disk for example). This gives the
>   impression that the performance of your hard disk is decreasing over
>   the first to the last disk sectors(it actually is, as you can see on
>   the first picture), as all SSDs are based on random access memories,
>   all the usable "area" of your SSD have the same speed and accessing
>   times, which corresponds to a linear performance over the entire disk.
>   This also explains why operational systems usually use the first
>   "area" and the first disk sections of the hard disks... For example,
>   Windows will boot faster and make disk I/Os better than it would be if
>   it was intalled on the last sectors.

[image]