# HDD I/O fast at first but gradually decreases?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, performance, io

I was benchmarking my WD 500 GB HDD in Ubuntu Disks several times and saw that the read speeds started at 140 MB/s, but it consistently would gradually decrease by a few MB/s with seemingly no floor. The same was for write speeds, but to a dramatically greater extent. What is the meaning of that? I am installing Ubuntu on it now; what might I expect the impacts will be on daily use as time goes on (i.e. how will that behavior manifest in daily use)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does performance of a regular hard drive decrease over the duration of a benchmark while SSD doesn't?](https://superuser.com/questions/440338/why-does-performance-of-a-regular-hard-drive-decrease-over-the-duration-of-a-ben)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the constant rotation speed of the disc. The reading and writing starts at the outer diameter of die circle. Within one roation there can be written or read more bits than on a rotation at a position with lower distance to the center. It's just physics and math.

The impacts on daily usage will be, that the moore space is used of the hdd, the lower gets the writing speed for new files. But lastly it should't get slower than the lowest result your benchmark returned. The reading speed will vary in conjunction to the physically reading position on the disc. The outer circle space will be read faster than the inner space.